# Using `fig.retina` in `knitr` chunk results in unexpected figure sizes

Tags: rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

According to the [documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/) the default for `fig.retina` in `knitr` is a numeric value of 1. I would expect, then, leaving the setting blank (example 1 below) would yield exactly the same image as in example 2 below where I specify `fig.retina=1`. Instead I'm finding that the default (#1) creates an image that is 60kb and setting `fig.retina=1` yields an image that is 25kb.

Perhaps explicitly setting `fig.retina` overrides other settings or something? Does anyone have an explanation for why leaving the chunk options blank results is a figure that is more than twice the size as setting `fig.retina=1` (which should be the default)?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  html_document:
    self_contained: false
---

```{r onefile_figretinaDefault}
#1. this is 60kb on disk
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```


```{r onefile_figretina1, fig.retina=1 }
#2. this is 25kb on disk
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```


```{r onefile_figretina2, fig.retina=2 }
#3. this is 60kb on disk
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```


```{r onefile_figretinaNULL, fig.retina=NULL}
#4. this is 25kb on disk
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```

```{r onefile_figretina1_owNULL, out.width = NULL, fig.retina=1 }
#5. this is 25kb on disk
ggplot(cars, aes(speed, dist)) + geom_point()
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `knitr` documentation is a bit misleading.  `rmarkdown` sets the default to a different value.  For example, I see the default as 2 in an HTML document.

You can see what the default is by printing the value within a chunk:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$get("fig.retina")
```

will give you the default, and

```
knitr::opts_current$get("fig.retina")
```

will give you the current value.

If you look at the `knitr` source code (it's on Github), you can see that the default is 1 (so the documentation is correct), but if you look at the `rmarkdown` documentation (or source), many of the output devices (e.g. `html_document`) change it.

Comment: Yes that is confusing! Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I agree these differences are confusing, but they are documented anyway: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html